# eclipse IDE font colour

Tags: eclipse, fonts, colors, preferences

When I writing code in eclipse and there is an error with my code, a red squiggly line appears below the error.

When I hover over the line a text box pops up. This box has possible fixes for my problem.

**My issue** is that this box has a black background with dark blue text, and I can not read the solutions.

I have gone through preferences; general and java and not been able to locate the item I need. I do not know the name of the popup box. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBGzj.png)

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: Added a screenshot. Can't embed as rep 1. It has been added as a link above. kgw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that specific style, but if you go to *Eclipse_installation_folder/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_xxx/css*, you'll find the stylesheets that you can modify to change Eclipse's appearance.

I was able to find the following in the dark theme (*e4-dark_globalstyle.css*).

```
Shell[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_IN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN'] > Composite,
Shell[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_IN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN'] > Composite Composite,
Shell[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_IN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN'] > Composite ScrolledComposite,
Shell[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_IN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN'] > Composite Canvas,
Shell[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_IN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN'] > Composite StyledText,
Shell[style~='SWT.DROP_DOWN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_IN'][style~='SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN'] > Composite Label {
/* Error information popup */
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    color: #CCC;
}
```

When I modified the color and background-color, it worked, but only when putting my mouse over the popup.  I hope, at least, this will give you a clue where to look.

You may get better help from the [Eclipse Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/89/).

Comment: Was able to find the above code and modify it. It did not work for me though. Thanks for your help, it gave me somewhere else to look.